# Stop applet execution on load, pause/resume using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, html, web

I'm making something of a java applet gallery for my website (processing applets, if you're interested) and I'd like to keep the applets from running when the site first loads. Then, when the appropriate button is clicked, a piece of javascript would tell the applet to continue execution until another button is pressed to stop it. I know that I can use appletName.start() and appletName.stop(), but it doesn't seem to work on load, at least not well. I'm using element.getElementsById( "applet" ) to get the applets to use the start and stop methods on. It slows Firefox to a crawl for some reason.

Comment: Question... why would you want to stop/pause the applet, then resume the applet?

Comment: The idea is that there is a gallery of java applets controlled by javascript. I'd like to stop execution of any applets that aren't currently visible, so the page doesn't bog down and/or crash the browser with all its java-ness.

Answer (score 0):

Do you inject the applets with JavaScript or are they already in the HTML?

You need to poll for `appletName.isActive()`, than you should get an applet that reacts to your pause/resume calls.